# Comment specific block of code in multiple files

Tags: linux, bash, perl

I've got multiple files with certain blocks of code, multiple lines, that I need to comment out.  I'm interested in some special blocks which contain a specific keyword:

> ic create

These block always begins with

> %put %str

and ends at

> %rcSet

**Example block as follows:**

```
  text
  text
  text

  %put %str(NOTE: integrity constraints);
  proc datasets library=TESTING nolist;
     modify TESTING_UPDATES;
        ic create not null (id);
        ic create not null (prsn);
        ic create not null (valid_from);
        ic create not null (valid_to);
        ic create not null (current_flag);
        ic create not null (active_flag);
        ic create not null (hist);
  quit;

  %rcSet(&syserr);

  %put %str(NOTE: integrity constraints);
  proc datasets library=TESTING nolist;
     modify TESTING_UPDATES;
  quit;

  %rcSet(&syserr);
```

There could be more blocks that start and end with specified keywords but do not have "ic create" keywords and needs to be ignored.

I've written a code which finds and displays all such blocks but I can't figure

1. How can I get these blocks which have desired pattern in middle, from start to end
2. What's the best way to comment, add * at the beginning of line, them all from start to end
3. The code should preferably be without any external modules, as not everyone reading this in future might have access to them

**Desired output:**

```
      text
      text
      text

*     %put %str(NOTE: integrity constraints);
*     proc datasets library=TESTING nolist;
*        modify TESTING_UPDATES;
*           ic create not null (id);
*           ic create not null (prsn);
*           ic create not null (valid_from);
*           ic create not null (valid_to);
*           ic create not null (current_flag);
*           ic create not null (active_flag);
*           ic create not null (hist);
*     quit;
*
*     %rcSet(&syserr);

      %put %str(NOTE: integrity constraints);
      proc datasets library=TESTING nolist;
         modify TESTING_UPDATES;
      quit;

      %rcSet(&syserr);
```

**My Perl code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @files = glob ("*.sas");

foreach my $file (@files) {
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Cannot open file: $!"; {
        while ( <$fh> ) {
                if ( /%put\s%str/ ) {
                print;
                while ( <$fh> ) {
                        print;
                        last if /%rcSet/;
                }
                print "-" x 20, "\n";
        }
}

__END__
```

Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: do you only want to `*` the IC lines or the entire block including the start and the end? Can you show the expected output?

Comment: Updated my question with desired output, thanks.

Comment: There's no need to escape percentage signs `%` in a Perl regex pattern.

Comment: No more escaping percentage signs.

Answer (score 2):

#### Update

For anyone wishing to avoid even the core module `List::Util`, you may remove the `use` statement from the code below and define the `any` operator like this

```
sub any(&@) {
    my ($f) = @_;
    $f->() and return 1 for @_;
    return 0;
}
```

---

I've used this file to test my code. It would have been much more appropriate if you had offered your own test file as we have to guess what your data contains, and we're writing code for free here

#### data

```
  text
  text
  text

  %put %str(NOTE: integrity constraints);
  proc datasets library=TESTING nolist;
     modify TESTING_UPDATES;
        ic create not null (id);
        ic create not null (prsn);
        ic create not null (valid_from);
        ic create not null (valid_to);
        ic create not null (current_flag);
        ic create not null (active_flag);
        ic create not null (hist);
  quit;

  %rcSet(&syserr);

  %put %str(NOTE: integrity constraints);
  proc datasets library=TESTING nolist;
     modify TESTING_UPDATES;
  quit;

  %rcSet(&syserr);
```

#### Perl code

This program expects the path to the input file as a parameter on the command line. The output is sent to stdout

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use List::Util 'any';

my @block;

while ( <> ) {
    my $status = /^\s*%put\s+%str\b/ .. /^\s*%rcSet\b/;

    if ( $status ) {

        push @block, $_;

        if ( $status =~ /E/ ) {
            if ( any { /\bic create\b/ } @block ) {
                s/^ ?/*/ for @block;
            }
            print @block;
            @block = ();
        }
    }
    else {
        print;
    }
}
```

#### output

```
      text
      text
      text

*     %put %str(NOTE: integrity constraints);
*     proc datasets library=TESTING nolist;
*        modify TESTING_UPDATES;
*           ic create not null (id);
*           ic create not null (prsn);
*           ic create not null (valid_from);
*           ic create not null (valid_to);
*           ic create not null (current_flag);
*           ic create not null (active_flag);
*           ic create not null (hist);
*     quit;
*
*     %rcSet(&syserr);

      %put %str(NOTE: integrity constraints);
      proc datasets library=TESTING nolist;
         modify TESTING_UPDATES;
      quit;

      %rcSet(&syserr);
```

Comment: "It would have been much more appropriate if you had offered your own test file as we have to guess what your data contains" - Thanks for the advise, I've updated the question for future readers.  I was wondering if there could be a solution without using modules?

Comment: @AshishKumar: Why do you want to avoid using modules?

Comment: I've noticed many times people coming here for one time solution (via Search engines) and sometimes they are unaware of the language, installation process or, worst of all, don't have access / rights to install the module altogether.  Therefore, I was looking for a solution which could benefit every user.

Comment: @AshishKumar: There is an attitude creeping in that it is somehow "better" to avoid using modules in Perl code, and ideas like this only encourage it. **a)** Removing the phenomenal CPAN library from your toolkit drastically limits the possibilities **b)** It isn't hard to install a module in a personal directory, and it is much better to teach people how to do that than to imply that modules are "bad" **c)** `List::Util` is a core module that is available with every standard installation of Perl **d)** It is unfair to have such hidden agendas that are revealed only after you get an answer

Comment: @AshishKumar: **e)** It should be up to the author of the answer whether he wants to cater for people who don't like to install Perl modules. It is your job to precisely specify ***your own*** requirement.

Comment: Many thanks, your solutions works for me.   I will remember to provide complete information and requirements in future.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You're working line by line, and trying to 'know' if you've got an 'ic create' in a stanza.

Therefore the way to tackle it would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $buffer;

while (<>) {
   if ( m/\%put\s\%str/ .. /\%rcSet/ ) {
      $buffer .= $_;
      next;
   }
   if ($buffer) {
      if ( $buffer =~ m/ic create/ ) {
         $buffer =~ s/^/*/gm;
      }
      print $buffer;
      $buffer = "";
   }
   print;
}


#handle the case of buffer being the last line:

if ($buffer) {
   if ( $buffer =~ m/ic create/ ) {
      $buffer =~ s/^/*/gm;
   }
   print $buffer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most Perl programs use only one `while (<>)` loop, but it is possible to nest them, which makes it easy to have different loop semantics for inner and outer loops. And I think it makes the code a bit clearer. The outer loop searches for the begin marker and the inner loop searches for the end marker.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# Outer loop searching for begin marker.
while (<>)
{
  if (/%put %str/)
  {
    my @block = ($_);
    my $is_ic_create = 0;

    # Inner loop searching for end marker.
    while (<>)
    {
      push @block, $_;
      if (/ic create/) {
        $is_ic_create = 1;
      }
      elsif (/%rcSet/) {
        map { s/^/* / if $is_ic_create; print } @block;
        last;
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    print;
  }
}
```

Comment: `map` is for *mapping* one list to another according to a function and shouldn't be used for its side-effects. `map { s/^/* / if $is_ic_create; print } @block` should be `for ( @block ) { s/^/* / if $is_ic_create; print; }`